# choosing column name in .csv file

Tags: bash

I'm really new to bash programming. I want to write the results of two variables into a .csv file. I use this command:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
        ip=$(dig +short $line)
        echo "${line}, ${ip}" >> file.csv
done < domains
```

It works file. It creates two columns in file.csv and  writes the result of $line in the first column and the result of $ip in the 2nd column.

I wanted to know if there is a way to choose a name for these columns. For example

column1 : $line & column2:$ip

Comment: Column names in csv are just the first row

Comment: Since the values of ${line}, ${ip} are inserted in a loop, how can I determine the column names then?

Comment: @Evert According to what you said, the first row contains the name of the columns, so isn't it possible to just write "echo "Line, IP" >> file.csv" before the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSV files column names are the contents of the first row, so (before your loop) you can write:

```
echo "Line,Ip" > file.csv.tmp  # Add columns in new temporary file
cat file.csv.tmp >> file.csv   # Append all the data of the original file
rm file.csv                    # Remove the original file
mv file.cvs.tmp file.csv       # Rename the temporary file
```

Or you can also simply use this other method:

```
echo "Line,Ip
$(cat file.cs)" > file.csv
```

I hope it helps.

---

As helen pointed out in the comments, if the file should be overwritten with every run then you can simply add `echo "Line,Ip" > file.csv` before the loop.

Comment: According to what you said, the first row contains the name of the columns, so isn't it possible to just write "echo "Line, IP" >> file.csv" before the loop?

Comment: But rereading the question, this does not seem to be the case. I'll edit my answer